# Cloudinary cl_image_upload vs cl_image_upload_tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, cloudinary

I am trying to enable direct image upload from browser to cloudinary. The problem that I have is that the image is not being uploaded given the below syntax.

```
<%= form_for(@product_image) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.cl_image_upload(:image) %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

If I replace this block

```
<%= f.cl_image_upload(:image) %>
```

with

```
<%= cl_image_upload_tag("product_image[image]") %>
```

the upload still does not happen. However, if I put both of them next to each other, then both will upload.

I compare the html generated by the 2 cloudinary helper methods and they generate exactly the same html code. Looking at the code for these 2 helper methods, it seems that one is calling another.

```
def cl_image_upload(object_name, method, options={})
  cl_image_upload_tag("#{object_name}[#{method}]", options)
end
```

and

```
def cl_image_upload_tag(field, options={})
  html_options = options.delete(:html) || {}
  if options.delete(:multiple)
    html_options[:multiple] = true
    field = "#{ field }[]" unless field.to_s[-2..-1] == "[]"
  end

  tag_options = html_options.merge(:type=>"file", :name=>"file",
    :"data-url"=>cl_upload_url(options),
    :"data-form-data"=>cl_upload_tag_params(options),
    :"data-cloudinary-field"=>field,
    :"class" => [html_options[:class], "cloudinary-fileupload"].flatten.compact
  ).reject{|k,v| v.blank?}
  content_tag("input", nil, tag_options)
end
```

If I really want to use just one block <%= f.cl_image_upload(:image) %>, then I also have to add extra javascript

$('.cloudinary-fileupload).cloudinary_fileupload();

In your opinion, what is the best way for direct from browser upload to cloudinary with Carrierwave?

Answer (score 0):

Cloudinary has a fully working sample project, which includes client-side uploads with the jQuery library, including CarrierWave integration. You can have a look and try it out:
https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/tree/master/samples/photo_album

Comment: Thanks Itay, I'll check it out.